# How to get a line break

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to copy the content right next to the checkbox in another div when change event is fired. I have almost done that but I cannot get a line break in another div. Here is my code:

This is the div I want to copy from

```
<div>
    <input  type="checkbox"/><label for="1">One</label><br>
    <input  type="checkbox"/><label for="2">Two</label><br>
    <input  type="checkbox"/><label for="3">Three</label><br>
    <input  type="checkbox"/><label for="4">Four</label><br>
</div>
```

This is the div I want to copy to

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

My jquery code would be:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
            var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
            return $(this).next().text(); 
            }).get();
            $("#myDiv").text(arr.join(' '));
          });
```

Also if there is any alternative method to get this whole jquery code done, I would surely like to know.

Thank You.

Comment: Instead of `join(' ')` you could do `join('<br>')`. For the rest your code looks fine.

Comment: No, putting <br> won't work, because specials chars will be escaped

Comment: Two side notes: 1. The `for` attribute is supposed to link a `label` to an `input` by the `input`'s `id`, but your `input`s don't have `id`s. 2. While it's valid to start an `id` value with a digit in HTML, it's very awkward to work with as a CSS ID selector cannot start with a literal digit (e.g., `#1` is an invalid selector). Since we use CSS selectors for styling and also frequently to look up elements, best to avoid starting IDs with digits (in general).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But yes, <br> is not working. It gets added as a string value.

Answer (score 1):

In that **specific** case, you could just change `text` to `html` and use `<br>` in your `join` call (but keep reading):

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).next().text(); 
    }).get();
    $("#myDiv").html(arr.join('<br>'));
    // ---------^^^^-----------^^^^
});
```

**But** that only works because it happens that the text of your checkbox labels doesn't have any `<` or `&` in it; if it did, it would be problematic.

A more robust solution grabs the HTML of the labels instead of the text, so that any `<` or `&` is handled correctly:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).next().html();
    // -----------------------^^^^
    }).get();
    $("#myDiv").html(arr.join('<br>'));
    // ---------^^^^-----------^^^^
});
```

Live example, with the labels changed to demonstrate the escaping (and with the two "side notes" from my comment on the question addressed as well):

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
        return $(this).next().html();
    }).get();
    $("#myDiv").html(arr.join('<br>'));
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="c1" type="checkbox"/><label for="c1">&lt;One></label><br>
    <input id="c2" type="checkbox"/><label for="c2">&lt;Two></label><br>
    <input id="c3" type="checkbox"/><label for="c3">&lt;Three></label><br>
    <input id="c4" type="checkbox"/><label for="c4">&lt;Four></label><br>
</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
$("#myDiv").html(arr.join('<br>'));
```

Here an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/10030/)

Using `.text()` function will escape the special characters, but
`.html()` function won't